# Peut on dire «replacement or resoldering of resistors» «remplacement ou ressoudant des resistances »

Tags: traduction, anglais

Comme le titre l'indique, peut-on traduire cette phrase :

> replacement or resoldering of resistors

par

> remplacement ou ressoudant des résistances ?

Comment: [Ressoudure](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ressouder) peut-être (plutôt que ressoudage).

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais plutôt :

> Remplacement ou ressoudage de résistances.

Voir [ressoudage](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ressoudage)